# Can't update user in post request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am successfully hitting the route and getting the request data. When I request('description') in my controller after I submit my form it shows the description. But for some reason it's not updating in my database.

```
public function personal(User $user){                            
    // Validate form
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'description' => 'max:107',
        'country' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Z]+$/' // Uppercase letters
    ]);

    $user->update([
        'description' => request('description'),
        'country' => request('country')
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

-

```
// controller.php
    Route::patch('/users/{user}/personal', 'UsersController@personal');

    // html

    <form method="POST" action="/users/{{$user->id}}/personal">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        <textarea name="description" maxlength="107"></textarea>

        <select name="country">
          ... options here
        </select>

        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing request in your function, try passing $request object

```
public function personal(User $user, Request $request)
{                            
    // Validate form
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'description' => 'max:107',
        'country' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Z]+$/' // Uppercase letters
    ]);

    $user->update([
        'description' => $request->description,
        'country' => $request->country
    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```